# Generate random number for x amount of time in BASH

Tags: bash, timeout, random

I would like to generate random numbers for "x" amount of time, but I'm not sure how to make it run for x amount of time (like 2 minutes for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah, nvm.. I figured it out lol.. This is my solution

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate random numbers for "X" amount of time.
TIMER='2m' # Default (2m) = 2 minutes
timeout -sHUP ${TIMER} bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do echo "${RANDOM}"; done'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
while true; do echo "$RANDOM"; done & sleep 2m; kill %1
```

It's a little bet less typing, and supports any time parameter that your local version of sleep supports.